# apply on group replicating complete MultiIndex

Tags: pandas

I have the following problem - the output of the calculation gives me two atomic_number fields:

```
In [7]: partition_functions
Out[7]: 
atomic_number  ion_number
14             0             11.291802
               1              5.866805
               2              1.004422
               3              2.000202
26             0             59.650557
               1             66.895978
               2             28.186253
               3              6.569105

In [8]: def group_func(group):
    return group[1:]/group[:-1].values
   ...: 

In [9]: partition_functions.groupby(level='atomic_number').apply(group_func)
Out[9]: 
atomic_number  atomic_number  ion_number
14             14             1             0.519563
                              2             0.171204
                              3             1.991397
26             26             1             1.121464
                              2             0.421345
                              3             0.233061
```

I tried a couple of things - including making a new Series and nothing worked.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: I must be blind. I don't see a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
def group_func(group):
    return (group / group.shift(1))

partition_functions.groupby(level='atomic_number').apply(group_func).dropna()
```

Which results in:

```
                            values
atomic_number ion_number          
14            1           0.519563
              2           0.171204
              3           1.991396
26            1           1.121464
              2           0.421345
              3           0.233061
```

Comment: Hi Rutger, thanks for your answer! That is a bit of a workaround - what I'm doing now is dropping one of the atom_numbers by creating a new index. I'm wondering: Why is this happening? When I return group instead of group[1:]/group[:-1] it works (doesn't do anything, but works)